# Why does this regex not work if I use a variable instead of directly using the respective string?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code:

```
function escape(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\\\$&');
}

function replace(str, needle, replacement) {
  var expr = '([^\\[]*)(' +
      escape(needle) + ')([^\\]]*)';
  return str.replace(new RegExp(expr, 'g'), '$1' + replacement + '$3');
}

document.body.innerHTML += replace('hello() [hello()] test()', '()', '@');
```

The problem is the following line:

```
var expr = '([^\\[]*)(' +
  escape(needle) + ')([^\\]]*)';
```

If I replace it with

```
var expr = '([^\\[]*)(' +
  '\\(\\)' + ')([^\\]]*)';
```

it works. I do not understand why the return value of the `escape` function cannot be used. I mean, it exactly returns `\\(\\)` if I test it with

```
alert(escape('()'));
```

What is my mistake?

Not working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rmof8pzv/
Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gpoy2rbt/

Comment: In a regex you only need a single backslash to escape a character. You are adding two backslashes (`'\\\\$&'`). (In your working example the string _literal_ `\\(\\)` is stored as `\(\)`.

Comment: @Ivar Thank you, I was already starting going mad. You should post this as an answer since this is exactly the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are mixing up the escaping of your backslashes.

You need to escape backslashes in string literals because the backslash is used to escape other characters as well. This means that the string *literal* `'\\'` is stored as `\` as you can see here:

```js
console.log('\\');
```

In a regex you need to escape characters with a single backslash as well, but if you do so in a string literal you need to double escape them for the above reason. This is why your working example works. But in your `escape()` function you are adding two backslashes instead of one. Simply change `'\\\\$&'` to `'\\$&'` and it should work fine.

```js
function escape(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
}

function replace(str, needle, replacement) {
  var expr = '([^\\[]*)(' +
      escape(needle) + ')([^\\]]*)';
  return str.replace(new RegExp(expr, 'g'), '$1' + replacement + '$3');
}

console.log(replace('hello() [hello()] test()', '()', '@'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the double back slash being escaped inside the `escape` function `'\\\\$&'` you don't need to escape that because it need to be escaped only once like `'\\$&'`. So changing the escape function gave me the expected result.

```
function escape(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

Comment: you don't have to escape most special characters inside a `[ ]` character group.

Comment: It does not work either. The `escape` function is from a stackoverflow answer. It works but not in combination with my other code somehow. See the fiddles I have appended.

Comment: @Anonymous sorry I misread your regex, it seems like you are doublescaping the replacement placeholder (`\\\\$&`) making it change the pattern (to `\\(\\)` instead of `\(\)` not matching the parenthesis anymore. I've update the answer